# Heat mapping forestry height trends using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, heat-map, polygonize, canopy-height-model

I am using ArcGIS and have access to Spatial and 3D Analyst extensions.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/c4k84]

I've attached a link to a picture of a 1m raster “canopy height model” which was derived from LiDAR and displays tree heights (in 5m intervals but can  obviously be adjusted). I do 3d models w/ a program that uses polygon inputs to derive height classes.

How can I convert this raster to a polygon and capture broad polygon classes?

(I can’t use raster to polygon as I work with 100’s of hectares at a time and an individual polygon for each raster cell would be far too much detail and slow the program down.)

I’m thinking of a heat map (?) type exercise which captures general trends as polygons. I’ve circled several polygons in blue that would be the ideal type of polygons I would like to capture…but ultimately I do need 100% polygon coverage.

I have access to SA and 3D analyst if that helps! In terms of accuracy, I'm not sure. As accurate as I can be without having 1m polygons or anything too small.

Comment: It would be best to insert your image into your question, not all users *can* or *will* follow links. It sounds like you're trying to generalize your CHM into regions with the final results being polygons... is that correct? I would suggest generalizing your raster before trying anything. How accurate are you intending the polygons to be?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS and have access to SA and 3D analyst if that helps! In terms of accuracy...I'm not sure. As accurate as I can be without having 1m polygons or anything too small.

Answer (score 1):

In order not to receive super small polygons after the conversion, try to first smooth / generalise your raster, i.e. using the `Filter()` or `FocalStatistics()` out of the Spatial Anaylist Toolbox. You'd have to play around using those in order to find the solution fitting your needs. The `FocalStatistics()` tool basically does the same as `Filter()`, except you have more choice on *how* you'd like to generalise your data. Try different neighbourhoods for instance or run the tool iteratively (use the generated output as the input raster for the next run with `FocalStatistics()`).

Finally use the `Reclassify()` tool to group your raster into integer values representing the different classes of canopy heights. Exporting this integer raster to polygons will result in full polygon coverage. If needed you could still perform "clean up" on your polygon data, using `Dissolve()` or `Union()` for instance.